# Why did auxiliary verbs in Kazakh got completely merged into one word in Turkish?

Tags: historical-linguistics, grammar, turkic-languages, auxiliary-verbs

Kazakh and Turkish belong to same language group.

But Kazakh is more archaic, Turkish is more modern.

In Kazakh, there are auxiliary verbs *otur*, *jur* , and *jatir* that become part of the word in Turkish:

root word:

war - *savaş* (tr), *sogis* (kk)

he is fighting him:
tr: *savaşiyor*

kk: *sogisip jatir*

why did the *jatir* got merged into the root word *savaş*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very complicated question:

---

firstly, there no archaic/modern distinction within these language: both have modern literary tradition. But they can keep archaic features of sub-levels  or even proto-conditions;

---

secondly, you have mistake with 'root word' because *savaş/sogıs* are *derivatives* from *•√saba-*, where *-ş/-s* are verbal noun *formants*; and *savaşiyor/sogısıp catır(jatır)* are *derivatives* from *√savaş-(mak)/√sogıs-(ıw)*, where *-ş-/-s-* is *the reciprocal*;

---

thirdly, Oghuz formant *-Iyor* isn't from *√cat-(jat-)* but from formerly verb *√yör(ü)-//to run* [it is cognate to *cür-(jür-)*];

---

fourthly, it need to clarify that these auxiliary verbs in this case are parts of the present tense - so-called *new praesens* - and they differentiate in their behaviour from the very same auxiliary verbs when they used for showing a mood or a modality (so another verbs used too): e.g. new praesens is *sogısıp cür* but as an auxiliary verb is *sogısıp cüredi* in the present or *sogısıp cürdi* in the past [there is *-A tur-* form additionally to the *-Ip Aux.Verb* form but only with *√tur-*]; there no such feature in the Oghuz branch except few languages/dialects that was contacted with Kipchak so there only *-Iyor* is *new praesens* [ similar but different situation within few Kipchak languages itself; there no so-called *new praesens* at all in some Kipchak languages, there is only simple present *-A-/-y-* ];

---

fifthly, *-Iyor* is grammaticalized *-A yör-* and it was corrupted by languages and dialects to even *-(I)(r)*;

---

sixthly, there was *-Ar* formant - so-called *aorist* or *present-future* -  in Kipchak and Oghuz branches, and for Kipchak branch it has tendency to determine the future with sporadically open/close vowels [i.e. *-Vr*] in it by different Kipchak languages/dialects; in the Oghuz branch it still an aorist but in some Oghuz language/dialects there happened *the contamination* with *new praesens* especially where it was corrupted to the *-Ir* than there is the tendency to indicate the present with *-Ir* formant and the future with *-Ar* formant. But sometimes the aorists defend to the contamination by the unmotivated round vowel,(i.e. *-Ur*): *-Ir* [present, aorist]:*-Ar* [future] vs. *-Ir* [present]:*-Ur* [aorist]:*-Ar* [future]; there are some another strategies for this by dialects;

---

seventhly, the very complicated question, but interesting and difficult to been described in few words; by the way, there is the fusion of "-Ip catır" form to the "-Ivatır" [in the colloquial speech; this is the first stage to possible more corruption, as in Oghuz branch; n.b. that "-Ip catır/etc.* as *new praesens* already has been grammaticalized (just because of its differentiating behaviour)] ; the verb *catır[jatır]* is interesting itself because it must be just *cat[<√cat-(ıw)]* as *tur* from *√tur-* but it is *catır*, possible explanations: there is an artefact of old aorist, or there is the contamination with *otır, tur, cür* forms.

---

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that Turkish *-yor* is the result of merging *jatir* to the verb. Turkish language belongs to Oghuz branch which has significant differences from Kipchak branch. Constructs similar to Turkish *-yor* exist in Turkmen and Azerbaijan languages.

yaz**ir** - he is writing (Azerbaijan)

yaz**ar** - he is writing (Turkmen)

All three languages belong to Oghuz branch.

> But Kazakh is more archaic, Turkish is more modern.

That's a questionable statement. Both Kazakh and Turkish originates from the common ancestor, Proto-Turkic language.

Answer (score 5):

The why? question is not answerable from a linguistic point of view, it just happened so. But there is a general phenomenon across languages named [grammaticalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization#Clines_of_grammaticality_%E2%80%93_cycles_of_categorial_downgrading) that describes the fate of words becoming a part of the grammar of the language: They tend to loose their autonomy and merge with another word, becoming an affix in this process.

Comment: maybe this is cuz people want to speak faster? like it's tedious to say 2 words - so "otur/jatir" becomes just "yor" in turkish?

Comment: Yes, but at the same time people still want to be understood correctly, so there is a delicate balance between speed and clarity. But this balance can be shifted towards speed when the expression becomes strongly conventionalized or even obligatory.

Comment: This is where (for instance) English contractions and fast speech forms like _wanna, hafta,_ and _gotta_ come from. They get used, they get frozen, they get expected and chopped down.